# Generating Crystal Reports from DataSets and DataTables

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I need to generate a report in Crystal Reports in an application in which there is only a stand-alone DataSet (not connected to any type of database).  Also, I need to generate a report based on the values in DataTable.

Could you please show me through, I am a newbie. I have a template, but I do not know how to generate a report from a DataTable, nor how to insert in into the templates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This article is just for you;

[Crystal Report with DataSet and DataTable using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CrystalReportNDataTable.aspx)

- Binding Our Report to our DataSource

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  using System.Data.OracleClient;
  using System.IO;

  namespace CrystalReportWithOracle
  {
      public partial class frmMain : Form
      {
          public frmMain()
          {
              InitializeComponent();
          }

          private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
              my_rpt objRpt;
              // Creating object of our report.
              objRpt = new my_rpt();

              String ConnStr = "SERVER=mydb;USER ID=user1;PWD=user1";

              OracleConnection myConnection = new OracleConnection(ConnStr);

              String Query1 = "select a.PROJECT_ID,a.PROJECT_NAME,b.GROUP_NAME from 
              tbl_project a,tbl_project_group b where a.group_code= b.group_code";

              OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(Query1, ConnStr);

              DataSet Ds = new DataSet();

              // here my_dt is the name of the DataTable which we 
              // created in the designer view.
              adapter.Fill(Ds, "my_dt");

              if (Ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
              {
                  MessageBox.Show("No data Found", "CrystalReportWithOracle");
                  return;
              }

              // Setting data source of our report object
              objRpt.SetDataSource(Ds);

              CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject root;
              root = (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject)
                   objRpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["txt_header"];
              root.Text = "Sample Report By Using Data Table!!";

              // Binding the crystalReportViewer with our report object. 
              crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

EDIT: Also you should look this;

[ADO.NET Datatable as Crystal Report datasource](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vscrystalreports/thread/8be775f5-57f8-45c7-aff2-194d3b1bf292/)

[How do I populate Crystal Reports, using a DataTable?](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/239480-how-do-i-populate-crystal-reports-using-datatable)

Comment: The Thing is my report is a template and it is being added to the project as a file and I need to load that and I do not have any crystal reports viewer actually. What should i do?

Comment: @Faulty I think you absolutly read this article http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/crystalreportsintroduction11082005014959am/crystalreportsintroduction.aspx