# how to create a crystal report C# without database, by using dataset and datatable and fill this datatable with my own variables?

Tags: c#, datatable, crystal-reports, dataset

I'm creating a windows form application, and I need to create a crystal report without database.

I know how to create a dataset and a datatable, but I dont know how to fill this datatable or clear it, and I dont know how  to display that crystal report on click on a button in my form.

I have 3 variables : id, firstname, lastname
I want to add these 3 variables values to my datatable of 3 columns to display them in crystal report.

I'm totaly new to crystal report!
Any Help Please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are asking.

```
            my_rpt objRpt;
            // Creating object of our report.
            objRpt = new my_rpt();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet("MyDataSet");

            DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyDataTable");
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);


            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("firstname", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("lastname", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1,"John", "Smith"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Mary", "Jones" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "Harry", "James" });

            // Setting data source of our report object
            objRpt.SetDataSource(ds);

            CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject root;
            root = (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject)
                 objRpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["txt_header"];
            root.Text = "Sample Report By Using Data Table!!";

            // Binding the crystalReportViewer with our report object. 
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt;
```

Comment: how to connect this datatable to crystal report ? and display these values in it?

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594954/generating-crystal-reports-from-datatables

Comment: In my case, i dont use a database, so i have to use  dataset and a datatable, but i dont know how to make connection between this datatable and the crystal report

Comment: I'm not using a database.  A DataSet consists of a collection of DataTables,  I updated my code to show this connection.  Also added the Cystal report code.